# Regular Expression Help - Brackets within brackets

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to develop a function that can sort through a string that looks like this:

```
Donny went to the {park|store|{beach with friends|beach alone}} so he could get a breath of fresh air.
```

What I intend to do is search the text recursively  for {*} patterns where there is no { or } inside the {*}, so only the innermost sandwiched text is selected, where I will then run a php to array the contents and select one at random, repeating process until the whole string has been parsed, showing a complete sentence.

I just cannot wrap my head around regular expressions though.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Gracious to everyone. Problem is slayed and staked.

Comment: @adbox: what was the solution? if it was one of the answers below, you should mark it as accepted. if it wasn't one of the answers, write an answer yourself so people with the same problem can learn.

Comment: To accept an answer, click on the checkmark icon next to that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions don't deal well with recursive stuff, but PHP does:

```
$str = 'Donny went to the {park|store|{beach with friends|beach alone}} so he could get a breath of fresh air.';

echo parse_string($str), "\n";

function parse_string($string) {
    if ( preg_match('/\{([^{}]+)\}/', $string, $matches) ) {
        $inner_elements = explode('|', $matches[1]);
        $random_element = $inner_elements[array_rand($inner_elements)];
        $string = str_replace($matches[0], $random_element, $string);
        $string = parse_string($string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The code is perfectly working and answers the question.

Comment: Downvote compensated. The code does the trick (although mine is nicer;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about maths theory behind this ;-/  but in practice that's quite easy. Try

```
$text = "Donny went to the {park|store|{beach with friends|beach alone}} so he could get a breath of fresh air. ";

function rnd($matches) {
    $words = explode('|', $matches[1]);
    return $words[rand() % count($words)];
}

do {
    $text = preg_replace_callback('~{([^{}]+)}~', 'rnd', $text, -1, $count);
} while($count > 0);

echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Regexes are not capable of counting** and therefore cannot find matching brackets reliably.

What you need is a [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).

*See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns).*

Comment: No, what he needs is a function which *uses* a regular expression. There is no need to solve the whole problem with a single regex.

Comment: Regex is overkill for such a simple operation. Save yourself some headaches later and write it "longhand" now.

Comment: No, he doesn't need a grammar and regexp is just the right tool for the job. See kemp's and mine answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str="Donny went to the {park|store|{beach {with friends}|beach alone}} so he could get a breath of fresh air. ";
$s = explode("}",$str);
foreach($s as $v){
 if(strpos($v,"{")!==FALSE){
  $t=explode("{",$v);
  print end($t)."\n";
 }
}
```

output

```
$ php test.php
with friends
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a lexer/parser. I don't know of any options in PHP (but since there are XML parsers in PHP, there are no doubt generic parsers). On the other hand, what you're asking to do is not too complicated. Using strings in PHP (substring, etc.) you could probably do this in a few recursive functions.

You will then finally have created a MadLibz generator in PHP with a simple grammar. Pretty cool.